# Xpath changing after the page gest loaded every time

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, dynamic

I am using Selenium WebDriver along with Java. I am trying to access the 'Login ID' text box in that page but every time I am Logging in and out, the XPath value against the 'Login ID' text box changes so I am unable to detect the 'Login ID' text box every time with the same code.

What modifications do I need to make in my code so that I am able to access all the dynamic XPaths with a single piece of code?

Comment: Ask the dev to assign it an unique id. Then you can find it whatever the dom is.

Comment: Use dynamic locators in the form of `xpath` or `cssSelector`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the html, you could use contains xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of what you could potentially use as a workaround

Type of xpaths:

- multiple matches: `//div[@class='class' and contains(text(), 'text')]`
- partial match: `//span[contains(class, 'class')]`
- starts-with: `//input[starts-with(@name,'input')`

These are more beneficial when handling dynamic elements and will be robust.

For more information please see: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-to-find-element-using-contains-in-xpath

Comment: Thank you very much Danny as your solution helped me. Much appreciations. Sorry for being late in replying.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped!