# Selenium Webdriver css selector onclick event for flight booking website

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying automation test on following website - http://www.arzoo.com
when we search flight, 
I am unable to click select on particular flight.
I used Xpath but it doesn't get the element if it's at bottom or middle of the page so then I need to use:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx2.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,750)", "");

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='Select']")).get(15).click();
```

but I don't want to use scroll to position. different screens will need different sizes.

I planned to use css sector but still no success.

Comment: What code base are you using to write your automated tests?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" onclick="selectFlight('az625_6E834_N_6E6246_N','');">Select</a>

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the below code inside executeScript()

```
let allSelectButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".booking-item-flight-details .booking-item-arrival a");

for(i=0;i<allSelectButtons.length;i++) {
   allSelectButtons[i].click();
 }
```

Comment: can u explain in more details

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'btn-primary')]")).click();
```

if not, try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'result_0')]/div/div/div/div[2]/a")).click();
```

See the following for reference:

- [Get Nth child of a node using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407781/get-nth-child-of-a-node-using-xpath)
- [Xpath changing after the page gest loaded every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472142/xpath-changing-after-the-page-gest-loaded-every-time/47473846?noredirect=1#comment81952171_47473846)

Comment: all button contains same class 'btn-primary'