# Python + Selenium -- How to click the search button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click the button using Python + Selenium:

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4w98 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _4w97" aria-
label="Search" tabindex="-1" data-testid="facebar_search_button" 
type="submit"><i class="_585_"></i></button>
```

Please let me know how can I use it with WebDriver? I tried XPath, by value but none worked.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and explain better what "none worked" means.

Comment: searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@value="1" and @label="Search"]') try this

Comment: @thebadguy it should be [@aria-label="Search"] not [@label="Search"]

Comment: Could you check if the button is in an iframe?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: The bad guy code actually works with Shekhar Semanta correction.

Comment: The right code will be --> 
      searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@value="1" and 
      @aria-label="Search"]')

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath :- `//button[@value='1' and @label='Search']`

searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@value='1' and @label='Search'])

Comment: `aria-label` instead of `label`. I guess OP manually reformatted his code.

Comment: searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@value="1" and @label="Search"])

Comment: It gives invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starts-with or contains:

Edit:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='_42ft' or @class='_4jy0']");
```

Edit1: In case of multiple classes 'contains' works mostly.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'_42f‌​t') and contains(@class, '_4jy0')]");
```

Let me know what you get!

Comment: Refer to Edit1 from my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@type, 'submit')]");
```

The top answer on the following Question explains xpaths in more depth: [Xpath changing after the page gest loaded every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472142/xpath-changing-after-the-page-gest-loaded-every-time/47473846#47473846)

Comment: use of contains is harmful sometimes . it also find elements that contains sub string *submit*

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```